# How does a manual commit work in kafka where multiple streams are created for one partition?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In official kafka confluence, this is how a high level consumer is written.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

To be specific, we create multiple streams under one partition to consume.

```
Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
```

Subsequently, we iterate in every stream in ConsumerTest. I want to understand how will manual commit work in this case? Manual commit is done by `consumerConnector.commitOffsets()`

We are consuming via multiple streams and consumerConnector is common to all of them. The first question is how is commitOffsets going to work? Is it going to commit accross all the streams? If so, is having a single stream only the way use manual commit? I am using kafka 0.8.2.2